# Adjusting z-index of angularjs typeahead directive

Tags: css, angular-ui, jquery-layout

I am using Angularjs typeahead directive in combination with jquery layout plugin. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rbfSByzsh8wc2f0aaBDA) is the link to the app I am working on. When I type an address into the input box, the list of autocomplete results get hidden behind the resizer. I have tried changing the z-index property of both the autocomplete list as well as the pane resizer, but nothing seems to be working. What is the best way to solve this?

```
.ui-layout-resizer-open {
    z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 2;
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this issue by telling `typeahead` directive to append suggestions list to the `body`. Just add `typeaheadAppendToBody` attribute along with other `typeahead` attributes:

```
typeahead-append-to-body="true"
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3RlEcNgH4Pviuu6SXs6y?p=preview